# How to stop transitions in D3.JS v3

Tags: d3.js

I would like to ask how to stop transitions in my Code.

I have a map that has plots that are loaded via csv, and the plots are successfully placed.

And I have created a Circle ( clickable ) that when on click. removes all the plots with the same color. ( grouped via class , so in my code there is a selectAll and removes all same colored plots by editing their opacity to 0 )

My transition is a repeating pulse ( run using function pulse, and within it it has a function repeat() )

so I can successfully remove and re plot my circle plots. but not the pulsing plots.

I'am using d3.js v3

Please see my code.

```
srcpulse.selectAll('.ThreatPulse')
            .data(data)
            .enter().append('g')
            .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'threatpulse-circle')
            .attr('cx', function (d) {
                return projection([d.srclon, d.srclat])[0];
                   })
            .attr('cy', function (d) {
                return projection([d.srclon, d.srclat])[1];
                   })
            .attr('r', 0)
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .each(pulse);

 function pulse() {
            var circle = srcpulse.selectAll(".threatpulse-circle")
                .data(data);

            (function repeat() {
                circle = circle.attr('class', function (d) {
                    if ((d.site == "Dublin") || (d.site == "Manila") || 
                        (d.site == "Hazelwood")) {
                        return "mnk-site-pulse"
                    }
                    else { return "incident-circle" }
                })
                    .transition()
                    .duration(800)
                    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
                    .attr('stroke', function (d) {
                        if ((d.site == "Dublin") || (d.site == "Manila") || 
                   (d.site == "Hazelwood")) {
                            console.log("dublin in");
                            return "lawngreen"
                        }
                        else { return "red" }
                    })
                    .attr('r', 30)
                    .style('opacity', 1)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(100)
                    .attr('r', 0)
                    .attr('stroke-width', 0)
                    .style('opacity', 0.5)
                    .ease('sine')
                    .attr('stroke', 'none')
                    .each("end", repeat);

            })();
        }

     legendticker.selectAll(".Legend")
            .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'legendcircle')
            .attr('cx', function (d) {
                return projection([-30, 40])[0];
            })
            .attr('cy', function (d) {
                return projection([-30, 40])[1];
            })
            .attr('r', 20)
            .style('fill', 'lawngreen')
            .on('click', function (d) {

                var active = mnksite.active ? false : true;

                newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;


                //d3.selectAll('.mnk-site-pulse,.mnk-site')
                    //.remove();
                //.style('opacity', 0);

                d3.selectAll("#mnksite").style("opacity", newOpacity);

                d3.selectAll(".mnk-site-pulse").attr('stroke', "none");

                mnksite.active = active;
                console.log("clicked");
            });
```

But as you can see there is a repeating transition, and even though I tried to use .remove() or .exit() or .transition() it does not stop..

Any Ideas how to fix this?

UPDATED CODE :

```
srcpulse.selectAll('.ThreatPulse')
            .data(data)
            .enter().append('g')
            .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'threatpulse-circle')
            /*.attr('class', function (d) {
                var c = "";
                if ((d.site == "Dublin") || (d.site == "Manila") || (d.site == "Hazelwood")) {
                    return 'mnk-site-pulse'
                }
                else { return 'threatpulse-circle' }
            })
            */
            .attr('cx', function (d) {
                return projection([d.srclon, d.srclat])[0];
                //return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[0];
            })
            .attr('cy', function (d) {
                return projection([d.srclon, d.srclat])[1];
                //return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[1];
            })
            .attr('r', 0)
            //.attr('fill', '#4287f5');
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .each(pulse);



function pulse() {
            var circle = srcpulse.selectAll(".threatpulse-circle")
                .data(data);
            console.log(cancelled);

            (
                function repeat() {

                circle = circle.attr('class', function (d) {
                    if ((d.site == "Dublin") || (d.site == "Manila") || (d.site == "Hazelwood")) {
                        return "mnk-site-pulse"
                    }
                    else { return "incident-circle" }
                })
                    .transition()
                    .duration(800)
                    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
                    .attr('stroke', function (d) {
                        if ((d.site == "Dublin") || (d.site == "Manila") || (d.site == "Hazelwood")) {
                            return "lawngreen"
                        }
                        else { return "red" }
                    })
                    .attr('r', 30)
                    .style('opacity', 1)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(100)
                    .attr('r', 0)
                    .attr('stroke-width', 0)
                    .style('opacity', 0.5)
                    .ease('sine')
                    .attr('stroke', 'none')
                    .each("end", function() {
                        if (cancelled === false) {
                            console.log("cancelled");
                            console.log(cancelled);
                            return repeat();
                        }
                        else if (cancelled === true) {
                            console.log("cancelled = true");
                            console.log(cancelled);
                            return endmnksitepulse()
                        }
                    });

            })();
        }



        function endmnksitepulse() {
            console.log("end");
            srcpulse.selectAll(".mnk-site-pulse")
                .transition()
                .style('opacity', 0)
                .attr('r', 0);

        }


legendticker.selectAll(".Legend")
            .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'legendcircle')
            .attr('cx', function (d) {
                return projection([-30, 40])[0];
            })
            .attr('cy', function (d) {
                return projection([-30, 40])[1];
            })
            .attr('r', 20)
            .style('fill', 'lawngreen')
            .on('click', function (d) {

                var active = mnksite.active ? false : true;

                newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;


                //d3.selectAll('.mnk-site-pulse,.mnk-site')
                    //.remove();
                //.style('opacity', 0);

                d3.selectAll("#mnksite").style("opacity", newOpacity);
                //d3.selectAll('.mnk-site-pulse').duration(0);

                mnksite.active = active;

                if (cancelled == false) {
                    console.log("cancelled = true");
                    console.log(cancelled);
                    cancelled = true;
                }
                else if ( cancelled == true)  {
                    console.log(cancelled);
                    console.log("cancelled = false");
                    cancelled = false;
                    //d3.selectAll(".mnk-site-pulse").each(pulse);

                }


                console.log("clicked");
            });
```

But whenever I try to Click again in an attempt to restart the transition, I get this  error :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42kRh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set a `cancelled` variable, which you set when you want it to stop.

Then you change the code where repeat calls itself:

```
.each("end", repeat);
```

to this

```
.each("end", () => { if (!cancelled) repeat});
```

Comment: Hi Mikkel, thanks for the response, sorry for replying late. I will try this out.

Comment: Hi Mikkel, apparently it doesn't work.. what is wrong with my code/ implementation here?

Comment: I added a bit of code here and it successfully stops the transition, but whenever I click again to start the transition again, it updates the cancelled variable but does not start the transition and I have this error. 

 I don't get what the error means as well.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '180' of undefined
    at d3.v2.js:3
    at Y (d3.v2.js:1)
    at Ji (d3.v2.js:3)
    at Array.Yl.attr (d3.v2.js:5)
    at repeat (testmap.js:138)
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (testmap.js:166)

Comment: I can't tell which line of your code the error happens at. You might have to set `cancelled = true` in order to restart the transitions

Comment: Hi Mikkel, I tried to tweek it a little bit, please see the updated code ( I edited the post), I have a photo of the error that I'm experiencing.